# AutoCompleteTextView suggestions can be customize?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using AutoCompleteTextView in my application for search option. In my case I want to show some suggestions along with image as drawable left/right to the TextView. How to filter some suggestion and add drawable resource while displaying the suggestios.Because this drawable I have to add for some options only. Can we give our own layout for the suggestions display?

Suggest me.

Regards
Murthy

Comment: _Yeah you can create a Custom AutoComeleteTextView for this. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905092/autocompeletetextview-like-android-default-messaging-application)_

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you search google on that ? =)
This is searchable.xml

This is manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.search"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"
            />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RecordActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider android:name=".SuggestionProvider"
                  android:authorities="com.example.search.SuggestionProvider" />

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".Main" />

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
</manifest>
```

This is main activity

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {

    private EditText text;
    private Button add;
    private RecordsDbHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDbHelper = new RecordsDbHelper(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        showResults(query);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())){

                Intent recordIntent = new Intent(this, RecordActivity.class);
                recordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
                startActivity(recordIntent);
                finish();
    }

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String data = text.getText().toString();
        if (!data.equals("")) {
            saveTask(data);
            text.setText("");
        }
        }
    });

    }

    private void saveTask(String data) {
        mDbHelper.createRecord(data);
    }

    private void showResults(String query) {


        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(SuggestionProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                                new String[] {query}, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Обновляем адаптер
            String[] from = new String[] { RecordsDbHelper.KEY_DATA };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
            SimpleCursorAdapter records = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.record, cursor, from, to);
            getListView().setAdapter(records);            
        }        
    }


   // res/menu/main_menu.xml
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;    
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search_record:
             onSearchRequested();
            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Record Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecordActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.record_activity);


        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            finish();
        } else {

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            TextView record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.record_header);
            int rIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RecordsDbHelper.KEY_DATA);

            record.setText(cursor.getString(rIndex));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search_record:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Suggestion provider:

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class SuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider{

    private RecordsDbHelper mDbHelper;

    public static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.search.SuggestionProvider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/records");

    //MIME типы для getType()
    public static final String RECORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                                  "/vnd.example.search";
    public static final String RECORD_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                  "/vnd.example.search";

    //Для матчера разных URI
    private static final int SEARCH_RECORDS = 0;
    private static final int GET_RECORD = 1;
    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = makeUriMatcher();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDbHelper = new RecordsDbHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        //Используем UriMatcher, чтобы узнать какой тип запроса получен. Далее формируем соответствующий запрос к БД
        switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                if (selectionArgs == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
                }
                return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
            case SEARCH_RECORDS:
                if (selectionArgs == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
                }
                return search(selectionArgs[0]);
            case GET_RECORD:
                return getRecord(uri);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
             BaseColumns._ID,
             RecordsDbHelper.KEY_DATA,
             SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};
        return mDbHelper.getRecordMatches(query, columns);
    }

    private Cursor search(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            RecordsDbHelper.KEY_DATA};

        return mDbHelper.getRecordMatches(query, columns);
    }

    private Cursor getRecord(Uri uri) {
        String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
            RecordsDbHelper.KEY_DATA};

        return mDbHelper.getRecord(rowId, columns);
    }


    private static UriMatcher makeUriMatcher() {
        UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        // Для записей
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "records", SEARCH_RECORDS);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "records/#", GET_RECORD);
        // Для подсказок
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);
        return matcher;
    }

    //Требуемые методы (наследуются от класса ContentProvider)
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_RECORDS:
                return RECORDS_MIME_TYPE;
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            case GET_RECORD:
                return RECORD_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                       String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

DB Helper:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class RecordsDbHelper {

    public static final String KEY_DATA = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;

    private static final String TAG = "RecordsDbHelper";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "datas";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "records";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" + KEY_DATA + ");";  

    private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();


    public Cursor getRecord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
        String selection = "rowid = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }

    public Cursor getRecordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = KEY_DATA + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(KEY_DATA, KEY_DATA);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
                BaseColumns._ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
        return map;
    }

    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }    


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS records");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    }

    public RecordsDbHelper(Context context) {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }


    public long createRecord(String data) {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATA, data);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

}
```

Woah! That's all =) Check out teh project on google code http://code.google.com/p/androidsearchexample/
Plus for the answer is the best reward =) Good luck!

Comment: I am not using this google searchable.xml because this is a dialog. But i want a search option for entire application . In my case the search box should be present in everyscreen in my application, but not onClick of any item . So i am using AutoCompleteTextView concept. Am i correct?

Comment: Well, in that way it would be useful to use QuickSearchBox http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html , as you always have a search button on your phone and you can call it everywhere..

Comment: QuickSearchBox uses searchable.xml right?. Then how can I use that.My intention is to add drawable for some search suggestion. I don't know how to filter those suggestions and how to add drawable for some suggestions based on the fileter values in AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: then this should help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html And did you do any research in this way? AutoComplemeTextView supports adapter, so i think you may add drawables via simple row customization. Just create Array or Base - Adapters and rewrite getView() method so that it returns your desired layout.